# Localization in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, localization, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to use localization in a .NET Core 3.1 application.
I've added the following to my `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
        new CultureInfo("en-US")
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE", "de-DE");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

In the assembly where I need the localization, I've created a folder named `Resources` and in it a resource file called `MailTexte.de-DE.resx`. In the same assembly, but in a different folder, I've added a class `MailTexte.cs`:

```
public class MailTexte
{
    public string ConfirmationMailTitel { get; } = string.Empty;
}
```

In the class where I need the localization, I've injected `IStringLocalizer<MailTexte> stringLocalizer` into the constructor and I'm trying to get the value with 
`var titel = this.stringLocalizer["ConfirmationMailTitel"];`

Unfortunately, when looking at the result, it says "Resource not found = true".

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the resources folder is not in the asp.net project, you must do the following:

```
        private readonly IStringLocalizer _stringLocalizer;
     
        public TestController(IStringLocalizerFactory stringLocalizerFactory)
        {
           _stringLocalizer = stringLocalizerFactory.Create(
            typeof(ConfirmationMailTitel).FullName,
            "ResourcesAssemblyName");
         }
```